# I have a list of integers that is called numbers in this code Print every number that is greater than 90 in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Here's my code :

```
 numbers = [76, 83, 16, 69, 52, 78, 10, 77, 45, 52, 32, 17, 58, 54, 79, 72, 55, 50, 81, 74, 45, 33, 38, 10, 40, 44, 70, 81, 79, 28, 83, 41, 14, 16, 27, 38, 20, 84, 24, 50, 59, 71, 1, 13, 56, 91, 29, 54, 65, 23, 60, 57, 13, 39, 58, 94, 94, 42, 46, 58, 59, 29, 69, 60, 83, 9, 83, 5, 64, 70, 55, 89, 67, 89, 70, 8, 90, 17, 48, 17, 94, 18, 98, 72, 96, 26, 13, 7, 58, 67, 38, 48, 43, 98, 65, 8, 74, 44, 92]

while numbers>=90: 
       print(numbers)
```

**Here the Output :**

Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 3, in  while numbers>=90: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Even if that would have worked, you would have an infinite loop. Why `while`?

Comment: I'm just trying it on my own. (Not too much involved in while and for loop just learning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = [76, 83, 16, 69, 52, 78, 10, 77, 45, 52, 32, 17, 58, 54, 79, 72, 55, 50, 81, 74, 45, 33, 38, 10, 40, 44, 70, 81, 79, 28, 83, 41, 14, 16, 27, 38, 20, 84, 24, 50, 59, 71, 1, 13, 56, 91, 29, 54, 65, 23, 60, 57, 13, 39, 58, 94, 94, 42, 46, 58, 59, 29, 69, 60, 83, 9, 83, 5, 64, 70, 55, 89, 67, 89, 70, 8, 90, 17, 48, 17, 94, 18, 98, 72, 96, 26, 13, 7, 58, 67, 38, 48, 43, 98, 65, 8, 74, 44, 92]

for number in numbers:
    if number >= 90:
        print(number)
```